# jQuery GETs as well as POSTs with IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, post

We're using jQuery.ajax() methods to request server data on a number of pages on our MVC 3 web site.  These requests are always marked with the 'POST' ajax parameter type and are typically invoked on page load or perhaps on a timer, that is to say, they are not a result of a user action (e.g. a mouse-click).

When we look at the (Elmah) error log we see a number of entries as follows:

> A public action method 'GetMessageStats' was not found on controller 'Inbox.WebUI.Areas.Application.Controllers.StatusController'.

The controller action is marked with the [HttpPost] e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetMessageStats()
{
   MessageStatsViewModel model = new MessageStatsViewModel
   {
      TotalNoMessages = MailDB.GetMessageCount(),
      MessagesInQueue = MailDB.GetQueueLength()
   };

   return Json(model);
}
```

and here is the invoking client script:

```
$(function() {
   var $totalMessages = $("#total-messages"),
       $queuedMessages = $("#queued-messages");

   function getStats() {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/Application/Status/GetMessageStats",
         dataType: "json",
         cache: false,
         success: function (data) {
            $totalMessages.text(data.TotalNoMessages);
            $queuedMessages.text(data.MessagesInQueue);
            setTimeout(function() {
               getStats();
            }, 15000);
         },
         error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorMessage, exception) {
            throw errorMessage;
         }
      });
   }

   getStats();

});
```

On investigation it appears that some browsers (IE7/IE8, but maybe others) seem to issue a GET request in addition to the required POST request.  It is noted that the user interface responds and behaves correctly under these browsers so the POST request is being serviced.

Elmah is reporting the user agent as:

**Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)**

Has anyone else seen this problem?  If so, have you found a way to avoid it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your client code, since that's where this happens.

Comment: What Diodeus says.  This is more then likely a client code issue.

Comment: View your server HTTP log for more information about these GET requests. Are they done before or after a POST and what UserAgent are used? etc.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the client script and also state the user agent string associated with these errors.  I will review the http logs later today.

Comment: My previous answer is wrong - check out this though -  http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/  The only thing is you're not setting your data - so it may not apply.

Comment: I have modified the jQuery ajax call in line with the recommendations highlighted in Danack57's link http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/  I'll let you know if this makes any difference (we were, for example, not passing an empty data object)

Comment: Modifying the style of the jQuery ajax call has made no difference, so my original code pattern stands.  One (more) odd thing I have noticed from the logs is that if the ajax call presents data parameters then the additional GET request is still made but NO parameters are appended to the query string, i.e. a GET is made against the base ajax url property.  I'm beginning to wonder if this might be a web crawler related issue?

Comment: @Neilski, I like your idea of the webcrawler.  Another possibility (although impossible for me to test) is that even though you are setting 'cache: false', the specific browser/version still 'tests' for a cached response using GET.  Depending on your dev tools, you might be able to test this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it is worth, re: the superfluous GET, I found that there were some toolbars/security services that would 'check' urls to make sure they were valid. I believe it was TrendMicro who had a Web of Trust type plugin that would re-poll sites to examine them for malware.

Have you tried using the shorthand ajax methods, like $.post()? Also, if you're getting data, is there a specific reason you need a POST?

If you generate a request through Fiddler or your tool of choice, do you get the same error in the response?

Comment: Hello John, I have tried using Fiddler, but I am unable to replicate the problem despite trying IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 Firefox and Chrome.  As you suggest, my suspicions are that this problem is being caused by some additional browser plugin.  The url itself is only ever referenced from this one script.  We tend to use POST whenever we want to submit data to the server - even if is is just simple query parameters.  In the example above we could equally use GET.  I will try $.post() to see if it makes any difference.  Thanks fro your help.

Comment: `TrendMicro` a huge love story with me. (Hear irony?)

Comment: Hi John, your original suspicions were correct.  We looked at another 'locked-down' web site and saw the same problems.  Being in a more controlled environment, it was easier to identify the errors and, as you surmised were due to the users running Trend Micro Titanium Internet Security 2012!  Thank you for your help - I have awarded you the bounty as a token of my appreciation.  The only question now remains is how to manage these errors - ignore them I guess?

Comment: I found my issues through the IIS logs - the IPs were all in Japan somewhere & the user-agents were conspicuously short. They all said IE 6, but not much else - i.e., it was TOO simple, most user-agents of desktop browsers have more than just 'Internet Explorer 6.0.' I'd suggest seeing if you can pinpoint the user-agent of the extra GETs and isolate them. It's hacky, but filtering for those would at least let you ignore them. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this happens when you have another function that is modifying the URL and appending a GET parameter. If that happens then IE has a tendency to send both a GET and POST request.

The function could probably be 'ajaxSend' which is the jQuery function that is called before the ajax request is sent.

The solution would be to not modify the URL directly, but to pass any extra parameters that are need into the request.

Info taken from:
http://www.justinball.com/2009/07/08/jquery-ajax-get-in-firefox-post-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: I'm not sure this is the same problem.  We are seeing a superfluous GET request (although specifying ajax type='POST').  Were also not modifying the url or passing any data - it's just a static link.

Comment: Can you should check your web server logs to make sure that the requests don't have any request parameters?

Comment: I've checked the logs and I can confirm that they are not showing any request parameters on additional GET requests

Answer (score 0):

The method that you are using in your javascript code is a GET method. So try removing [HttpPost] from the controller action method.

Or to make it a post method, pass post data like this.

```
url: "/Application/Status/GetMessageStats",
data: {},
dataType: "json",
```

Try  this. Not tested..

Comment: Hi Sunil, if you review the original post, you will see that the $.ajax() call is decorated with the parameter type='POST'.  Accoring to the jQuery documentation this should override the default 'GET' to a 'POST'.  I appreciate that I can make the error go away by removing the [HttpPost] attribute from the controller, but this is not the point, what I'm trying to establish is how an GET gets initiated when the code doesn't invoke it.  Yesterday, out of 250 page requests, the spurious GET was only seen 19 times.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem once. The solution for me was to add another setting value:

```
processData: false
```

to the jQuery ajax call.